# How to publish public user profile data in Meteor-AngularJS only when needed

Tags: angularjs, meteor

In my app I want people to be able to visit public user profiles. Obviously I don't want to publish all the users' data at once, but only when they are visited. With Iron Router, I had

```
  waitOn: function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('getPublicProfileData', this.params._id);
  }
```

in the route for the public profile. What is the equivalent for AngularJS's ui-router?

Answer (score 2):

I did the whole "answer-your-own-question-while-formulating-the-question-for-SO" thing, so I figured I'd post my solution:

```
.state('profile', {
  url: '/profile/:userId',
  templateUrl: 'client/templates/profile.html',
  controller: 'ProfileCtrl as profile',
  resolve: {
    getProfile($stateParams) {
      return Meteor.subscribe('getPublicProfileData', $stateParams.userId);
    }
  }
});
```

Make sure to include $stateParams in the resolve function so you can grab the id in the Meteor subscription.